# Changing star amount in MUI Rating

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, icons, jsx, font-awesome

So I have been messing around with MUI and Font Awesome. With Font Awesome, it has an incredibly easy feature that allows for a ternary operator to be used to change the star amount based off of the value of the rating. For an object with a rating of 4.5, it will proceed to show 4 and a half stars. I have been trying multiple ways (all just hopeful but obviously wrong ways) in an attempt to use MUI icons in place of the Font Awesome ones because I think they are visually more appealing. The only difference on the screen here as opposed to the Font Awesome screen is that my usage of StarIcon and others would be replayed with the Font Awesome equivalent. Could someone please let me know what exactly I am doing wrong?

```
import React from 'react'
import StarIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Star';
import StarBorderIcon from '@mui/icons-material/StarBorder';
import StarHalfIcon from '@mui/icons-material/StarHalf';

const Rating = ({ value, text, color }) => {
  return (
    <div className='rating'>
      <span>
        <i style={{color}}
        className={
          value >= 1
          ? <StarIcon />
          : value >= 0.5
          ? <StarHalfIcon />
          : <StarBorderIcon />
          }
        ></i>
      </span>
      <span>
        <i style={{color}}
        className={
          value >= 2
          ? <StarIcon />
          : value >= 1.5
          ? <StarHalfIcon />
          : <StarBorderIcon />
          }
        ></i>
      </span>
      <span>
        <i style={{color}}
        className={
          value >= 3
          ? <StarIcon />
          : value >= 2.5
          ? <StarHalfIcon/>
          : <StarBorderIcon />
          }
        ></i>
      </span>
      <span>
        <i style={{color}}
        className={
          value >= 4
          ? <StarIcon />
          : value >= 3.5
          ? <StarHalfIcon />
          : <StarBorderIcon />
          }
        ></i>
      </span>
      <span>
        <i style={{color}}
        className={
          value >= 5
          ? <StarIcon />
          : value >= 4.5
          ? <StarHalfIcon />
          : <StarBorderIcon />
          }
        ></i>
      </span>
          <span>{ text && text }</span>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Rating
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ready solution from MUI. Or if you want, you can use the following code:

```js
import React from "react";
import StarIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Star";
import StarBorderIcon from "@mui/icons-material/StarBorder";
import StarHalfIcon from "@mui/icons-material/StarHalf";

const Rating = ({ value, text, color }) => {
  return (
    <div className="rating">
      <span>
        {[...Array(Math.floor(value))].map((key) => (
          <i key={key} style={{ color }} className={<StarIcon />} />
        ))}
        {value - Math.floor(value) && (
          <i style={{ color }} className={<StarHalfIcon />} />
        )}
        {[...Array(5 - Math.ceil(value))].map((key) => (
          <i key={key} style={{ color }} className={<StarBorderIcon />} />
        ))}
      </span>
      <span>{text && text}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Rating;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using [`Rating`](https://mui.com/components/rating/#main-content) component from MUI? If you want to display half star, change the `precision` prop to `0.5`

```
<Rating precision={0.5} defaultValue={0.5} />
<Rating precision={0.5} defaultValue={1} />
<Rating precision={0.5} defaultValue={1.5} />
<Rating precision={0.5} defaultValue={2} />
<Rating precision={0.5} defaultValue={2.5} />
<Rating precision={0.5} defaultValue={3} />
<Rating precision={0.5} defaultValue={4.5} />
<Rating precision={0.5} defaultValue={4} />
<Rating precision={0.5} defaultValue={4.5} />
<Rating precision={0.5} defaultValue={5} />
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]